# Connection String for Mysql Connection

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have following settings for mysql Database:

[image]

I have made connection string as:

```
server=localhost;database=Ink_ProductionJob;Port=3306;username=root;password=''
```

**Code:**

```
connection = New MySqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("ConnSQLString"))
connection.Open()
```

But Gives me error:

```
Authentication to host 'localhost' for user 'root' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Unknown database 'ink_productionjob'
```

Plese help me whats wrong in this.

First time establishing MySql and .NET connection.

Plz Help.

[image]

Comment: you havenot mentioned the password in the connection string in order to connect to that DB

Answer (score 0):

The unknown database error typically means that you are specifying a database that doesn't exist. Are you sure that the database name (not the table you need) is ink_productionjob ?